# Handling quotes from user inputted text in SQL insert query

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, odbc

Just come across an issue on an Ajax form I have where it's not allowing the form to be submitted due to quotes inputted by the user filling in a description field.

I'm connecting to my database via ODBC and am using an Ajax form to insert the values into the database.

I tried using the following

```
$problemDescription = addslashes($_POST['problemdescript']);
```

but the error remained the same, which is...

```
"PHP Warning:  odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 's'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SMT_Request_DevWIP\board\newJob.php on line 89"
```

Here's my insert query within php...

```
//Statement to insert into table
$SQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.[table1] (requestorName, requestedDate, problemDescription, Attachment, Status, Category, Reason, Action_Required,
    Area, Model, Board, Side, Revision, Line) VALUES ('$requestorName', '$requestorDate', '$problemDescription', '$addattachment', '$Status',
    '$Category', '$Reason', '$actionRequired', '$Area', '$Model', '$Board', '$Side', '$Revision', '$Line')";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is classic [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your application *will* be compromised or broken by this because you're trusting user input and you cannot ever trust user input.

You need to be using prepared statements/parameterized queries. This will *properly* handle your user input and make it safe from SQL Injection attack. Depending upon which driver you're using, there are slightly different ways to do it. The short version is you create a query with placeholders for the inputs, then feed values into those placeholders via a function (*not* string replacement).

[Microsoft has documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-perform-parameterized-queries?view=sql-server-ver15) for their driver; if you're using another driver, reference its documentation.